# How to convert a string to C# code in the SELECT of C# LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv, string-conversion

I'm trying to re-arrange / re-order a csv file through LINQ.
After I have calculated the arrangement of the columns, I need to create a new csv file in that arrangement.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546155.aspx

I'm using similar code to write a new file(in this case: 3 columns):

```
IEnumerable<string> queryLINQ =
                from line in lines
                let x = line.Split(',')
                select x[3],x[1],x[2];
```

But, the no.of columns are quiet huge in the problem(80) and the arrangement is received in a dynamic way(positionArray[]) so the column arrangement after the SELECT part is generated in a string. 'count' is the no.of column here.

```
        string selectCol = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++)
        {
            string col;
            if(k+1<count)
            {
                col= "x[" + positionArray[k] + "],";
            }
            else
            {
                col= "x[" + positionArray[k] + "]";
            }
            selectCol += piece;
        }
```

I'm not able to use the 'selectCol ' in the SELECT part as it is genating the file with the x[someNumber].

How do I convert the 'selectCol ' string so that it gives me the desired result?

Is there any other alternative to this?

Comment: What are `positionArray` and `colPosArr`?

Comment: The LINQ query isn't correct (`Cannot use local variable 'x' before it is declared`)

Comment: what about select x[2],x[0],x[1];?

Comment: Why to force doors wide open? Use Oledb instead of spliting text data! Oledb framework provides functionality to read comma separated data!

Comment: You might be better off using CsvHelper -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Comment: @codroipo, There is only one array containing the rearranged order positionArray[]. Let x = line.split(',') will set a array so declaration is not vital. It works.

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan, need to generate a bigger combination od 80 columns approx.

Comment: @MaciejLos, requirement specified. If I had that flexibility would have used pHp or Linux for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding the problem correctly. But here is anotherway of achieving what you want.

```
//assuming this is the new order of columns you want
  int[] positionArray = {2, 1, 0};
  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\testcsv.csv");

  var newLines = lines.Select(p =>
  {
    var columns = p.Split(',');
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var i in positionArray)
    {
      if (sb.Length > 0)
      {
        sb.Append(",");
      }
      sb.Append(columns[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }).ToArray();

  System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\testcsv2.csv", newLines);
  Console.WriteLine("Spreadsheet2.csv written to disk. Press any key to exit");
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I like the idea (+1), I answered (_using `Linq`_) extending this approach.

Comment: For comparatively smaller CSV the execution is perfect and I'm able to get the desired result. But as the CSV that I'm processing is huge(around 80) columns, the file being generated has the header column okay but the records are jumbled up. Is it the problem with CSV or do I need to customize the C# code?

Comment: Could you share an example of the file somewhere, then I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

With giving respect to @Captain0 (other answer), I got the `Linq` approach for you.

Specify the columns order in the `positionArray` and you get the desire order.

```
int[] positionArray = { 2, 1, 0 };

var flines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\testcsv.csv");

var arranged = flines.Select(line => line.Split(','))
                     .Select(x => string.Join(",", x.Select((s, i) => x[positionArray[i]])))
                     .ToList();
```

And arranged lines you can write to new file using `File.WriteAllLines`.

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\testcsv2.csv", arranged);
```

Comment: This is really helpful, but x[positionArray[i] generates "Array out of bound" error as i=count of array.

Comment: @Abhirup is there any problem? solution working for you?

Comment: I just checked, is working for me.  make sure postionArray starts from `0 ` index

Comment: Also just make sure that `postionArray` _count_ and columns _Count_ matches.